# How Do I Debug My Android Apps on a BlackBerry Priv?

Tags: android

I tried the usual tap-seven-times-on-the-build-number process to get a BlackBerry Priv recognized by my Ubuntu machine for debugging. While I could get into developer options and enable debugging, I didn't get the MAC address authorization dialog, and running `adb devices` showed `no permissions`.

How do you get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to whatever rules file you are using in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` for your Android devices, or create something like `51-android.rules` in there:

```
# BlackBerry Priv
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fca", ATTR{idProduct}=="8032", MODE="0666"
```

Then, unplug from the Priv, run `sudo service udev restart` at the command line, and plug in the Priv again. You should get the MAC address authentication dialog and can proceed as normal.